# Qual è il significato di "veste chiassosa"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Mi sentivo ormai parte di un potere legittimo, universalmente ammirato, aureolato di cultura d’alto livello, e volevo vedere quale **veste chiassosa** si stava dando il potere che avevo avuto sotto gli occhi fin dall’infanzia, il volgare piacere della sopraffazione, la pratica impunita del crimine, i trucchi sorridenti dell’ossequio alle leggi, lo sfoggio dello sperpero com’erano incarnati dai fratelli Solara.

Ho trovato che uno dei significati di veste è:

> (*poet*.) Il corpo umano, rispetto all'anima

(da *Lo Zingarelli*,  Vocabolario della Lingua Italiana), quindi lei si riferisce al personaggio di Michele Solara cui lei sta cercando nel rione? Giachè il carattere di Michele può essere descritto come chiassoso/rumoroso.

Mille grazie.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Ho letto il libro e credo sia interessante (per capire il contesto della frase della domanda) sapere che questo "potere che avevo avuto sotto gli occhi fin dall’infanzia" che appare nel brano è impersonato nella figura di Michele Solara per Elena Greco, l'io narrante. Al suo ritorno al rione dove aveva trascorso sua infanzia, Elena scopre che Michele si trovava a Posillipo, dove stava arredando una lussuosa casa in cui si sarebbe trasferito dopo il suo matrimonio. Elena ha questi pensieri quando cerca di andare a trovare Michele a Possilipo.

Answer (score 5):

Una *veste chiassosa* è un vestito che fa “rumore agli occhi”, quindi sgargiante, vistoso.

Il soggetto che potrebbe “indossare” questa veste è *il potere*. È un modo figurato: la protagonista è curiosa di sapere in che modo questo potere, che si esplica in sopraffazione e crimini, si mostra alla gente e si immagina che lo faccia in modo vistoso. Non si riferisce quindi al carattere “chiassoso” di Michele Solera, ma al suo modo di mostrare il potere che ha.

Comment: Discordo. "Veste" non ha a che fare con vestiti, bensì con il modo di porsi e di voler apparire (vedi definizione 3 https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/veste.shtml

Comment: Per si è d'aiuto, @egreg, guarda il mio commento sotto la domanda.

Comment: @Nico Infatti: *veste* è usato in modo figurato, come detto nella risposta e come dice l’etichetta “fig.” per il significato 3 nel dizionario citato.

Comment: L' etichetta fig. non dice che "vesta [sia] un vestito, come scrivi tu.

Comment: @Nico: nel dizionario che hai linkato, il punto 1. spiega che il significato fondamentale di “veste” è quello di un certo tipo di indumento; il punto 2. descrive un uso esteso del significato fondamentale, il punto 3. un significato figurato e così via. Sono tutte varianti di uno stesso significato base. Diverso sarebbe il caso di voci diverse, relative a omofoni che non condividono uno sesso etimo e uno stesso significato fondamentale, come per esempio “treno” nel senso di convoglio e “treno” nel senso di canto funebre. Spero di essere stato sufficientemente chiaro.

Comment: @dag Infatti io ho scritto che si trattava di un senso figurato come in (3). Chiaramente si tratta di un` origine comune, ma non del fatto che "veste" in questo senso sia una metafora per vestiti, come affermato. Inoltre, in linguistica si parla di omonimi e non di omofoni per cui dovresti un attimino informarti. Last but not least "spero di essere stato sufficientemente chiaro" ha due letture: (1) "spero di essermi spiegato bene" NO. (2) "Spero che tu abbia capito la mia lezione" No: perché qui non si tratta di impartire lezioni.

Comment: @Nico: Si dà il caso che siano veramente [omofoni](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/omofono) (oltre che omografi); ma se ti piace di più omonimo, fai pure. Poi, ti chiedo scusa se non mi sono spiegato bene: che cosa non ti è chiaro?

Comment: @Nico: Che ti ha fatto di male la parola “omofono”? È una parola della lingua italiana, nonché un termine tecnico della linguistica. Cf. per esempio il _Dizionario di linguistica_ a cura di G.L. Beccaria (p. 522), la [_Grammatica italiana Treccani_](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/omofoni_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) e così via. Come ami tanto dire, informati! :)

Comment: @Nico No, gli omofoni possono non essere omografi; in francese accade spesso, come in “cent” e “sang”; in italiano non è generalmente possibile per parole singole (ma ci sono *hanno/anno*, *ho/o*, *hai/ai*, *ha/a*) e il dizionario Treccani propone “da canto” e “d'accanto” che sono omofoni per via del raddoppiamento sintattico. Le accezioni di *veste* nel dizionario citato non sono omonimi/omofoni/omografi: sono *la stessa parola* in diverse *accezioni*, due delle quali figurate, dove il vestito è immaginario. Ma sempre vestito è.

Comment: @egreg Ti prego di rileggere il filone. Io non ho mai scritto che si trattasse di omo-whatever. Questo termine l'ha introdotto dag. Ti do ragione sul fatto che veste è figurato e derivato da vestito, ma questo è proprio quello che ricopre il significato di (3). Mi farebbe piacere continuare in chat, se ti va.

Comment: @Nico Veramente è *vestito* che deriva da *veste* tramite *vestire*. Non si tratta di un derivato, ma della stessa parola adoperata in un'accezione figurata. Esempio: "essere in un mare di guai”. Qui non c'è il mare in senso proprio, ma figurato: non è una parola diversa, è proprio la stessa. Quanto agli omonimi/omofoni, è forse vietato inserirsi in una discussione se si hanno argomenti da segnalare? Non mi risulta. Siccome sostieni che gli omofoni siano necessariamente omografi, ti porto esempi in cui questo non accade.

Comment: @egreg Non ci stiamo capendo. Il discorso dell`omofonia e dell`omografia l' ha messo in ballo dag e qui non è pertinente. Nel caso in questione il mio punto è che "vesti" nel senso di apparire deriva da "vesti" nel senso di abiti. Qui concordo con te. Il fatto è che la registrazione del dizionario che cito non rende trasparente questo nesso. Quindi non credo che discordiamo essenzialmente.

Comment: Mllle grazie per il vostro aiuto. Quando leggo in Italiano uso il WordReference online e Linguee, che spesso mi danno un contesto, ma loro sono Italiano-Inglese.  A volte, Reverso, dove non cerco parole ma espressioni, e anche presenta i significati dentro una frase completa, quindi in costesto.  Quando quei non sono abbastanza, cerco nello Zingarello che mi é disponibile via Kindle.  Per i libri in Italiano versione Kindle, il dizionario italiano è Zingarello e si può scaricare nel Kindle.  Purtroppo non so come caricare un'immagine dello schermo del Kindle con la definizione di 'veste'.

Comment: @Humberto Don't worry: reporting the definition is more than sufficient and the screen shot is not needed.